# How to define a default value for a field

Tags: newmips

I am creating an entity with a field `Activity` and I would like this field to have a default value of "100%`".

How to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "Activity" is a field with type string, you can set a default value like this:

`add field Activity with type string and default value MyDefaultValue`

You can do the same for "date" type:

`add field Activity with type date and default value today`

Or a "datetime" type:

`add field Activity with type datetime and default value now`

In your case, I would say you should try something like:

`add field Activity with type string and default value 100%`

Comment: `set field Activity with default value 100%` did not work. I had to delete the field and create it again. Hopefully there was not yet many data.

Comment: In this specific case, you can edit code of "create.dust" view  and set value to 100%